# login prompt when opening office document in office moss 2007 only in prod

Tags: sharepoint-2007

We have 2003 windows server with moss 2007. We get the windows login prompt when opening 2010 office doc. I removed the http handler verbs  from web config but still the site prompts for the credentials. It is a forms auth site with anonymous acccess enabled. Weird part is removing the verbs worked in development but in production it seems removing the verb has no effect. I checked if client integration was enabled in the auth provider. We have SP service pack installed in development not in production. But I am not sure what is going on. I will appreciate any clues.

Answer (score 0):

One solid recommendation is to use a product like Fiddler on the client to see what kinds of things are being requested on the client side.  In many cases, the office clients try to reach back to SharePoint to check things like versions, authors, check in/out status, etc.  This kind of thing can cause the client to prompt for authentication.

Comment: thanks for your response. I checked Fiddler. The prod is not declining the options call. Server should decline it. That is the issue.